How to compile a project linked grpc dynamic library without version using cmake?
I have compiled the grpc dynamic library locally and I'm using find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED) in my project. However, the final linked library is grpc++.so.1.46 instead of grpc++.so. This is causing my program to fail on other servers unless they have the same version of grpc installed.
is there something wroung with my setting?
I think that something may be wroung in my grpc building?
